# ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed: Cannot find module 'handlebars'

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js, html-webpack-plugin

I've recently erased all `node_modules` and did a fresh `npm install`. And keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Cannot find module 'handlebars'

  - compiler.js:76 
    [wallet-admin]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:214 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [wallet-admin]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:214:10

  - Compiler.js:403 
    [wallet-admin]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:403:12

  - Tapable.js:67 Compiler.next
    [wallet-admin]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:67:11

  - CachePlugin.js:40 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [wallet-admin]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:40:4

  - Tapable.js:71 Compiler.applyPluginsAsync
    [wallet-admin]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:71:13

  - Compiler.js:400 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [wallet-admin]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:400:9

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

    ERROR in Cannot find module 'handlebars'
```

Not sure what is going on...I've tried changing all versions of:
`html-webpack-plugin`, `webpack`, `handlebars-loader` thinking it is a versioning issue. It doesn't seem to be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Thankfully I figured out my own issue...in my `webpack.config.js` file under modules, I had the handlebars loader as:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      // this should be /\.handlebars$/
      test: /\.hbs$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'handlebars-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

But for some reason it needed the extension to be `.handlebars` instead of just `.hbs` even though my file is a `.hbs`. One mystery solved, another found. But it works!

Comment: Did you install the handlebars-loader as well? I forgot to do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by installing handlebars:

```
npm i handlebars --save-dev
```